# What application can open the .waveform file that the Voice Memos app creates?

Tags: iphone, voice-memo, waveform

I plugged an iPhone into my Ubuntu desktop and browsed the available files. In the Recordings directory I could see my voice memos, including a `.waveform` file, which I understand contains the visual plot of the audio. What application can open this file?

Comment: Did you google search before asking this question?

Comment: @IronCraftMan: yes, why? Have you found a link giving the answer?

Answer (score -1):

the .waveform file looks to be a vector file to display the audio waveform on a grid.
- jdio -